# Logging without exclusive locks on Windows

Tags: python, django, logging, azure

According to [Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html), under Windows "logging opens the files with exclusive locks".

In fact, in Django, with a configuration like this:

```
'handlers': {
    'logfile': {
        'level':'DEBUG',
        'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': 'myapp.log',
        'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024,
        'backupCount': 9,
        'formatter': 'standard',
    },
},
```

when the application is executed on Windows Azure Websites (under IIS + WSGI), the log file can't be read by any other application until the Django application is stopped.

Is there a way to log to a file under this environment (Windows Server, IIS, WSGI) without the file being opened in exclusive mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file yourself however you want, and pass the resulting stream to a `StreamHandler`.